# Service interface provided but not exported or used warning in module-info class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, module-info, intellij-idea2017

> ```
> Java9 - jdk-9+181
> intelliJ - 2017.2.2 built on August 9,2017
> ```

The [`java.management.rmi`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.management.rmi-summary.html)'s `module-info.java` implementation is somewhat like:

```
module java.management.rmi {
    ...
    requires transitive java.management;

    exports com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi to java.management;

    provides javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider with
        com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi.ClientProvider;
    provides javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerProvider with
        com.sun.jmx.remote.protocol.rmi.ServerProvider;
}
```

For both the `provides` statement I got to see a compiler warning stating

> Service interface provided but not exported or used

I ended up guessing wrong when I tried using these in another module as:

```
module interactor {
    requires java.management.rmi;
    uses javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider;
}
```

The warning still remains.

Furthermore, I could also reach [`java.management`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.management-summary.html)'s module to find

```
uses javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider;
uses javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerProvider;
```

What's the reason for this warning still and how could this be solved?

Attaching screenshot as per the ask in comments:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with the warning? I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I am going through the module-info.class from the library itself. Have attached the screenshot of the intelliJ warning.

Comment: OK, I reproduced it too. Looks like an IDEA bug.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample to reproduce.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Sure. Have raised it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178041) as well.

Comment: Have you copied the `provides` directives from java.management.rmi into your own module by any chance?

Comment: @AlanBateman No. I just created another module `interactor` for myself and included the directives as shared in the question.

Comment: @AlanBateman Was there any suspect if I would have copied the directives anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future references, this might turn up to be relevant due to some regressions in IntelliJ updates, answering this myself.

This was a bug with IntelliJ and was tracked at [IDEA-178041](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178041) which resulted in:

> omitting some JDK or library modules from a module graph used to generate
>   warnings.

---

***Update September 7, 2017***

The issue has been fixed with **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 EAP** build.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.2099.14, built on September 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```